# php how to add php code in the twitter callback url?

Tags: php, url, twitter, callback

I am trying to start a new app on dev.twitter.com, and in the callback URL I want to pass a link like: `www.text.com?number=<?= $var?>` but it won't let me.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Edit: my link will eventually look like this: `www.text.com?number=123456`

But it will depend on who is logged in, so the number could be any 6 numbers, so I'm thinking the callback URL has to have that var inside it.

Comment: Are you able to print the full URL on screen to make sure that the URL is being constructed properly?  Or are the variables being trimmed only when the user is sent back to your app from Twitter?  I don't think twitter does any trimming, so the issue is probably related to how you construct the callback url.  Hard to tell without any other code context though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the complete URL in an `oauth_callback` parameter when you get a `request_token` from Twitter. The specifics are detailed in the [authentication documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#request-token). For example you would have something like `oauth_callback=http://example.com/callback.php?number=123456` and with the request token will be an attribute of `oauth_callback_confirmed` set to a value of `true` so you know that Twitter will honor the custom callback URL.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you assume twitter is even running php? Even so they certainly wouldn't let you execute arbitrary php code in a callback they make.

Please explain what you really want to do. What you are asking isn't clear.